# How to configure GeoServer for web hosting on window xp?

Tags: geoserver

I want to access my data (shp, img, kml, tiff file) through IE, Google chrome or Mozilla, via local hosting (then through LAN). How to configure the GeoServer, so that the client (IE, chrome) can access the data and can perform some operations like add, update, delete and store the points, lines and polygons on the map.

I have windows xp 32-bit, GeoServer 2.2.2, PostgreSQL 8.4, PostGIS 1.5.
I am new to GIS. I have tried extensive search for the solution, but I am unable to configure my GeoServer.

It is requested to please give a step by step solution for the problem. 
Thanks for your suggestions and comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you take a look at [The OpenGeo Suite](http://opengeo.org/products/suite/) (Community Edition) - that should expose you to the 'geoserving' technology and you will quickly figure out how everything should be connected before connecting the individual parts yourself. The site also has great handson tutorials that will quickly accelerate your knowledge.

With the OpenGeo Suite your GeoServer is 'auto-configured' and you can connect to it through your browser easily on the localhost, 'through LAN should be easy to figure out.

Comment: Hi Erick!
Thanks for your suggestion. I hope it is paid software (OpenGeo suit). The supported formats are not clear for free version. I want to know the procedure or broad steps for web hosting using GeoServer. 
Thanks and regards

Answer (score 1):

To extend Erik's answer, if you want a tutorial then I would recommend the OpenGeo Workshops, found here http://workshops.opengeo.org/

There is a free version of the OpenGeo Suite called the Community Edition that you can download, install and use for free but you have to support it yourself rather than ask OpenGeo for support.

For supported formats look at the GeoServer documentation which is an excellent resource.

Answer (score 0):

If you install QGis full, it includes OSGeo4 Web server which runs over one of Apache "flavours". And once installed it runs as a service in Windows and you can connect through localhost or 127.0.0.1 from your browser. I'm not using it but I tested a time ago and it worked.

Comment: Yes I also install QGIS. I will also consider your suggestion for hosting my data on LAN or locally on system using QGIS. If you provide a link of a tutorial for web hosting it will be more helpful to me. Thanks.

Comment: Well, you can find lot of tutorials online that show how to configure your own web server. I don't know how your knowledge of networking is and I don't think this forum is the proper place to find an answer, but google how to run a web server and you'll find tons of info.